# flask optional url parameter not working

Tags: python, url, flask

```
@mod.route('/participate/<survey_id>/', defaults = {'work_id':None}, methods = ['GET','POST'])
@mod.route('/pariicipate/<survey_id>/<work_id>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def participate(survey_id, work_id):
   /* do_something .. */
```

I can access `http://localhost:5000/participate/512dc365fe8974149091be1f` or `http://localhost:5000/participate/512dc365fe8974149091be1f/`
and if I fire up a debugger I can see that `work_id = None`.

If I try `http://localhost:5000/participate/512dc365fe8974149091be1f/512dc365fe8974149091be1f`or `http://localhost:5000/participate/512dc365fe8974149091be1f/512dc365fe8974149091be1f/` I get 404.

why is this happening? Is there something I've done wrong with routing rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second route has a typo in it :)

```
@mod.route('/pariicipate/<survey_id>/<work_id>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
```

should be

```
@mod.route('/participate/<survey_id>/<work_id>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
```

Comment: Happens to the best of us :) PS: you should mark the answer as accepted