# How to handle missing parameters in URL with Flask/Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, flask, url-parameters

Currently, my website has two drop down boxes on it whose values, upon form submission, translate to two URL parameters "myState" and "myShelter". For example:

https://www.atweather.org/forecast?myState=CT&myShelter=181

I'm now adding a third box and there will be a third corresponding parameter called "myTrail". My question is this: how can I make it so that if someone directly submits a URL with just the two parameters, the browser will not error out with a bad request? I would want the user to see the page as though "myState" and "myShelter" were picked, but "myTrail" was just left unselected.

I tried looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032066/flask-optional-url-parameters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166142/flask-optional-url-parameter-not-working), but I don't think these are quite the same situation as what I'm asking about. I'm using Flask under Python 3 and currently handle this route like so:

```
@app.route('/forecast', methods = ['GET'])
def forecast(loc_state = None, loc_id = None):

    """
    Handles rendering of page after a location has been selected
    """

    loc_state = request.args['myState']
    loc_id = int(request.args['myShelter'])

    ...and a bunch of other logic for rendering the page...
```

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `request.args.get()` method allows to get the argument if it exists.

```
# return None if the argument doesn't exist
trail = request.args.get('myTrail')

# return 'x' if the argument doesn't exist
trail = request.args.get('myTrail', 'x')
```

After this, just handle the value to return the way you want.